# Nexus Repo Migration and updating.

Tags: nexus, devops

Trying to upgrade Nexus 2.1.4 Repo to 3.X. This is what i have done till now and what what went wrong!
-- installed the 3.0.2 version on the same machine in a different port (8090) Then  opened the UI and tried doing the upgrade agent and there was no upgrade agent in 3.0.2.
-- so i installed 3.1 on the different port and came across a java exception error in nexus Repo UI while migrating stuff from 2.1.4 (installed on port 80). I found out that one need to be at-least on 3.2.4 V to migrate. 
-- now i installed 3.6 on a different port (8082)in the same machine. couldn't start nexus service now. which i was able to for other nexus version in other ports.

Comment: You couldn't start NXRM3.6 at all?  What error are you seeing?  Is there a typo in your NXRM2 version?  NXRM2.1 is not upgrade supported.  See https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrade+Compatibility+-+Repository+Manager+2+to+3.  If you're not bound to a version see recommendation that always upgrade to the latest of both NXRM2 and NXRM3.  This will have the least bugs.  It may require you to upgrade your NXRM2 server first (it definitely would if your version is 2.1).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was running on AWS ec2-instance on t2.medium. It may sound bizarre but as soon as i upgraded to t2.large. the problem was solved.